# Loading ISO8851 text file to TextField()

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

How can I load .txt ( ISO8859-1 ) text file to TextField() from flex?  file is located in same folder with .SWF file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Deleted old post from here, see history for details.*

I found the answer for you.  Good news: no need for PHP magic!  Here's how to do it:

```
var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
ldr.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
ldr.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler);
ldr.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, errorHandler);
ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function (event:Event):void {
    var bytes:ByteArray = ByteArray(ldr.data); 
    var text:String = bytes.readMultiByte(bytes.length, "iso-8859-1");
    ...
});
ldr.load(new URLRequest('http://server.dom/path/to/your-file'));
```

You need to substitute "iso-8859-1" with the appropriate encoding.  You can find the [list of valid encodings here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/charset-codes.html).